# Proving that $x\in E^{o} \iff B_{r}(x)∩ E^{c}\not= \varnothing$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I know it is so easy proof. But I am confused.

### Remark:

$x\in E^{o} \iff B_{r}(x)∩ E^{c}\not= \varnothing$

### Proof

(İf) suppose $x\in E^c$ and $B_{r}(x)∩ E^{c}=\varnothing$

Then we have $B_{r}(x)⊆ E$ then, $x \not\in E^o$

But i cannot do and not if part. Please show me thank you

Comment: What do $E^o$ and $E^c$ mean?

Comment: Closure, interior signs. @ZevChonoles

Comment: First one şa interior. Second one is complement @ZevChonoles

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: I have not known this   Sorry and thank you @Lord_Farin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a (topological) metric space. Let $E\subseteq X$. What you want to prove is that $$E^\circ=X\smallsetminus \overline{X\smallsetminus E}$$

That is, the interior of a set is the complement of the closure of the complement of $E$. If this looks unclear, draw a picture.

**P**

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose $x\in E^\circ$. Then there exists a ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ such that $B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq E$ *strictly*. It follows $$B(x,\epsilon)\cap (X\smallsetminus E)=\varnothing$$  so $x\notin \overline{X\smallsetminus E}$.

($\Rightarrow$) Now suppose $x\notin \overline{X\smallsetminus E}$. This means that there exists a ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ such that $$B(x,\epsilon)\cap (X\smallsetminus E)=\varnothing$$

But this means $B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq E$; so $x\in E^{\circ}$.

**ADD** If we let $E$ be $X\smallsetminus F$ for some $F$; we get the shorter

$$(X\smallsetminus F)^\circ =X\setminus \overline F$$ which tells how to interchange the interior and closure operations when complementation is used.